# Export ObjectSID & Samaccountname

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export

Currently not receiving an export for the ObjectSID within the text file, what will need to be adjusted? Only having each line currently start with ";" then the samaccountname

```
$ADObjects = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(msexchextensionattribute23=*)" -Properties samaccountname,objectsid -Server myserver1.com
Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\AD001CountReport.txt -Append -InputObject ($ADObjects.Count + " Objects with msexchextensionattribute23 set found") 

foreach($ADObject in $ADObjects)
{
    $Export = $ADObject.objectsid + ";" + $ADObject.samaccountname
    $Export | Out-file ("C:\temp\AD001ObjectReport" + ".txt") -Append
    $Export = $null
}
```

Comment: It sounds like objectsid is blank. Have you verified that that's the correct property name?

Comment: `$adobject.SID` (example : S-1-5-21-2889043008-4136710315-2444824263-3544) or `$adobject.ObjectGUID` (example : e1418d64-096c-4cb0-b903-ebb66562d99d).

Comment: @briantist When performing a direct pull, I am getting similar results that sodawillow has:     `Get-ADUser user1 -server myserver1.com -Properties *`

Comment: However when doing a similar pull from `Get-ADObject`, then it is unable to identify the object within the domain

Comment: @sodawillow when doing the `$adobject.sid` there are no results given as well

Comment: Had to get a conversion script done for the sid determination, all is well just not going to add to this script at the current time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string concatenation fails, because the `objectSid` property is an object of type `System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier`, and you can't add/append a string to that. Use the object's `Value` property to get an SID string that you can work with:

```
$Export = $ADObject.objectsid.Value + ";" + $ADObject.samaccountname
```